# Return value is true of interface with implementing class when using instanceof in Java

Tags: java

I'm self-taught Java and I'm a bit confused about using "instanceof" in Java. Basically I know to use instanceof, however I'm having a hard time with this case. I write an interface, then use a class to implement that interface. Next I want to check if the interface has instanceof with the implementing class. I tried but the return value is only "false" but I want it to return "true" how should I write it? Can I achieve that goal ?Is there any sample code or suggestions for me? I would be very grateful and I would appreciate it. Sorry I'm a newbie, thanks.

```
interface Demo {
}

class A implement Demo {
}   

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
   Demo demo = new Demo() {};
   boolean result = demo instanceof A ;  // I want result is "true";
   System.out.println(result);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want the result to be true?

Comment: `demo` isn't an instance of `A` so `result` won't be true. Note that `new Demo() {}` would be an anonymous implementation of the interface and thus different from `A`. Try `Demo demo = new A();` - that should make `demo instanceof A` true.

Comment: I want to check Demo has instanceof with A at runtime

Comment: Well, just read the last sentence of my previous comment. If you want to check if `demo` actually refers to an instance of `A` then you must create the instance accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you gave runs perfectly fine. `result` is false, because `demo` is ***not*** an instance of `A`. In fact, it is the other way around. Because `A` implements `Demo` all instances of `A` would return true when they are checked to be a `Demo`.

You can define `demo` to be an instance of `A` and then check if it is an instance of `Demo`:

```java
Demo demo = new A();

boolean result = demo instanceof Demo; // now it is true
System.out.println(result);
```

**Edit:**
Changed the declaration of `demo` because of the comment of @Thomas (Thanks!)

Comment: `demo instanceof Demo;` or even `demo instanceof A` don't make much sense if the type of `demo` is `A`. The compiler knows that and allows you to use `demo` like the instance of  `A` or `Demo` that it is. However, if you use `Demo demo = ...` i.e. define the type of `demo` to be `Demo` then it _could_ refer to an instance of `A` or something else - and now the check makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can not create object of interface because interface is basically a complete abstract class. That means Interface only have deceleration of method not their implementation. So if we don’t have any implementation of a method then that means if we create object of that interface and call that method it compile nothing as there is no code to compile

```
interface Demo {
}

class A implements Demo {
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Demo demo = new A();
        boolean result = demo instanceof A ;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: With `A demo = new A();` the `instanceof` check doesn't make much sense. I assume you mean `Demo demo = new A();`. Also note that `new Demo(){}` _is_ possible, this basically defines an anonymous implementation and creates an instance of it in one statement.

Comment: @Thomas I forget to change object name

Comment: That didn't improve things :) - It's not the variable name that I was refering to but the type.

Comment: @Thomas That time i also change `class instanceof interface`

Comment: Well, if we know `A implements Demo` then `a instanceof Demo` doesn't tell us (and the compiler) anything new. Since `a` is of type `A` we already know that `a` also is an instance/implementation of `Demo`. Now if `a` where of type `Demo` then all we and the compiler know is that `a` is refering to any instance of `Demo` but we don't know whether it is an instance of `A` or something else. That's where the check comes in handy. Different example: `Number n = Long.valueof(1);` - `n instanceof Long`, `n instanceof Integer` etc. make sense now, `n instanceof Number` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`A implement Demo` and so:
`object with type A instanceof Demo` will be `true`, but not vice versa.

Ideally, `Demo` knows nothing about `A`.

And you shouldn't create an instance of interface.